# typeError: Cannot read property 'dtInstance' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-datatables

I'm trying to implement angular-datatables by Louis Lin with angular2.

when I try to get instance of Datatable it gives **typeError: Cannot read property 'dtInstance' of undefined** .

I'm referring steps from the documentation from [here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/dt-instance)

below is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit,AfterViewInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
import { EmployeeService } from '../services/employee.service';
import { Employee} from "app/services/employee";
@Component({
selector: 'app-employees',
templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})

 export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {  
 employees: Employee[];
 private datatableElement: DataTableDirective;
 dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
 constructor(
 private employeeservice:EmployeeService,
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private router: Router,
 ) { 

 }
 ngOnInit(): void {
 this.getEmployee(); 
 this.dtOptions = {
  paginationType: 'full_numbers',
  displayLength: 5
  };
 }
displayToConsole(datatableElement: DataTableDirective): void 
{
datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => 
console.log(dtInstance));
} 
getEmployee(){
this.employeeservice.getEmployees()
.subscribe(
    employees =>{ 
        this.employees = employees; 
        console.log(this.employees);
    (error:Response) => console.log(error)
  },
 )     
}

 deleteEmployee(employee){
 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Employee ?")) {
 console.log(employee.id);
  var index = this.employees.indexOf(employee);
  this.employees.splice(index, 1);

  this.employeeservice.deleteEmployee(employee.id)
    .subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.emp_data = employee;
      },
      err => {
        alert("Could not delete employee.");
        // Revert the view back to its original state
        this.employees.splice(index, 0, employee);
      },
      () => this.router.navigate(['/employees'])
      );
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using `datatableElement` before it has data, you could use a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)  to make sure it has data.

Comment: Tried using Promise like,
`ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = this.http.get('data/dtOptions.json')
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }`
but it is giving, Promise is not assignable to type void

Comment: Here is an example of how I use the promises, hope this works for you https://jsfiddle.net/0bghsjf8/

Comment: It seems your code is in angular1, i'm using angular2 , can you show a example if you are using angular2?

Comment: @AlanTorres you should improve your answer to show what to actually do to make it work. At least add an example as in the comment for other people to immediately see.

Comment: @AlanTorres do yo have any example on this?. I am also getting the same error, but i don't know how to use promise to make it work.